# Is there an easy way to do Compatibility QA testing for web app?

Tags: cross-browser-testing

I am working on a project that has a fair amount of daily bug/design changes that are minor but need to be tested in all major browsers / OSs. Does anyone know of a way to make this easier? It really is quite painfully to manually test...

At least IE allows me to test w/ older versions of their browser via the developers tools. How do they accomplish this? Do they emulate their older browsers w/ javascript?

Can a browser's default behavior be emulated with CSS? So that I can see how something will look in IE by loading an ie.css in my chrome browser?

Comment: Be careful about /only/ using IE's developer tools for compatibility testing. I've found numerous discrepancies between the dev tools and the real browsers that I, as a tester, can't rely on the tools anymore. Modern.ie is a great place to get all of IE's browsers for free and run them in virtual machines.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop manual testing then you are going to have to invest some effort into automating your tests. The cost of creating such tests can be measured against the time saved from manual testing and the assurance that your project / site is working from a user perspective.

**UI Acceptance Tests**

It is not a hard task to create automated UI acceptance tests that are driven by either Selenium / Watir / Watin. Keep in mind that automated UI acceptance tests generally test the functionality from a user perspective vs the look and feel of the CSS.

**Cross Browser CSS Testing**

Again, there are multiple tools for the job and you will need to pick one that works for you. For example here are several you can review:

- http://www.browserstack.com/
- http://crossbrowsertesting.com/
- http://browsershots.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yup, we use Saucelabs.com to automate our tests from visual studio in C#. Highly recommended to automate your test. Save loads of time. In addition we have used crossbrowsertesting.com and browser stack but found both to lack the capability/innovative approach of saucelabs.com. All we now do is call a method which communicates with the saucelabs service, so we no longer have to write new scripts every time we want to test a change.